# Drools Pricing Rule Decision Table Example

Tags: drools

The sample code being discussed [here](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.0.1.Final/drools-docs/html_single/index.html#d0e18500) in the latest Drools docs seems out of sync with the example code in the github [repo](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools/tree/master/drools-examples/src/main/java/org/drools/examples/decisiontable). Can anyone point me to the correct source, if it exists?

Answer (score 0):

Go with the Drools 6 example code. The documentation still contains a lot of hangovers from Drools 5.

As a rule, any examples you see which refer to `Knowledge` rather than `Kie` are from Drools 5 and earlier.